# Last step installing Ubuntu in VMware takes long time

Tags: installation, vmware

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 on VMware in my Win7 32 big system. So far the last step "Reticulating Splines" has been going on for more than 20 minutes, and it looks normal without error pops out. Is something wrong or do I just have to wait?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot, please?

Comment: Hi, I couldn't add images as my start reputation is only 1 and I need 10 to do that. But it's a quite simple window, with "Install" title, in the panel "Ask questions? blabla~", and at the bottom a progress bar at its end with "Reticulating splines"

Answer (score 0):

it's done.

1. ShutDown guest
2. Virtual Machine Setting, remove the autoinst (both in sata and floppy disk)
3. Start the guest

Ta-DA!